# Pandas Groupby First Value in Column

Tags: python, pandas

Is there a way to get the first or last value in a particular of a group in a pandas dataframe after performing a particular `groupby` ?

For example, I want to get the first value in `column_z` but this does not work :
`df.groupby(by=['A', 'B']).agg({'x':np.sum, 'y':np.max, 'datetime':'count', 'column_z':first()})`

The point of getting the first and last value in the group is I would like to eventually get the difference between the two.

I know there is this function: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#taking-the-nth-row-of-each-group

But i don't know how to use it with my use case, getting the first value in a particular column after grouping.

Comment: Try 'column_z': 'first'

Comment: Jesus, that simple

Comment: Also, no need to use the numpy functions when those functions are precoded in pandas `.agg({'x':'sum', 'y':'max', 'datetime':'count', 'column_z':'first'})`

Comment: with `groups = df.groupby('mall_id')` you get `groups` and with `get_group()`  you can manipulate that df then `df.iloc[0][column_name]` you get first value in paticular column